# Order divs in table-like structure with equal dynamic margin

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox

I'm not huge fan of bootstrap, so I was wondering if it is possible without it.

I have 6 divs which I want to order in 2 rows and 3 cols. I want the space between each row/col to be exact. I can do this by calculation but was wondering if there is smarter way around.

Note that .item height 50px is just for the example and is not set in the original code but it takes the height it needs to fit the content.

Also If I remove the .container height it will mess the horizontal blue line. I really do not want to rely on .container height.

I think it will be pretty easy with some JS which sets the height but I'd rather skip that and just use .container height instead. Thanks!

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-content: space-between;
  width: 500px;
  height: 125px;
  background: blue;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.item {
  background: red;
  width: 30%;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div class='item'> item1 </div>
  <div class='item'> item2 </div>
  <div class='item'> item3 </div>
  <div class='item'> item4 </div>
  <div class='item'> item5 </div>
  <div class='item'> item6 </div>
</div>
```

EDIT:
Since I can see there is no way without JS I'll just use the .container's height.
If somebody prefers the JS - here is a JQuery solution

```
$('.container').height(
    $('.item').height()*2 +
  (($('.container').width() - 3*$('.item').width()) /2)
);
```

Thanks for the answers!

Comment: either us `flexbox` or `css-grid` in combination with `grid-gap`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you need to fully support IE11 & 13 you can use CSS-Grid: `display: grid;`. You create a 3 column layout with the use of: `grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);` which will splitt the space into 3 equal columns (1fr = 1 fraction).

Then use the grid-gap property to exactly define the gap space.

PS: you dont have to use classes on the grid-cards. You can select them (and onyl them) with the use of: `.container > div`

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 500px;
  background: blue;
}

.container > div {
  background: red;
  min-height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div> item1 </div>
  <div> item2 </div>
  <div> item3 </div>
  <div> item4 </div>
  <div> item5 </div>
  <div> item6 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I see that you use grid-gap. In my example the gap between them is calculated by the display: flex and justify-content: space-between; making it dynamic. Is there a way to set the gap that way?

Comment: what do you mean with a dynamic gap? If your approach is working then where is the issue and why do you need a fix to it?

Comment: I really want to get rid of .container's height. If I remove it they go side-by-side in the vertical direction. Meanwhile because of the width and the space-between the gap between them is calculated on point and it is not specified by me. So I was wondering if I can make it so the vertical gap is equal to the horizonal one without me specifying the height of the container.

Comment: no there is no way without JS. How should it it work? either the height is calculated by the content or the height is preset.You would have to work with margins and give them a fixed height. So at one point you always need to define the height to get a specific gap height.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can plot `.item` in two lines and stripes without specifying the exact height and width, and width using **flex**.

First add `flex-flow: wrap column` for `.container`. This will build `.item` in the order you want. And for the indentation, you can use `gap` rule.

For the width, use the `calc()` function to limit the flex width for `.item`. Like that:

```
flex: calc(100% / 3);
```

```css
:root {
  --gap: 20px;
}

.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: wrap column;
    gap: var(--gap);
    width: 500px;
    height: 125px;
    background: blue;
    padding: var(--gap);
}

.item {
    flex: calc(100% / 3);
    background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="item">item1</div>
    <div class="item">item2</div>
    <div class="item">item3</div>
    <div class="item">item4</div>
    <div class="item">item5</div>
    <div class="item">item6</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I see that you use gap. In my example the gap between them is calculated by the display: flex and justify-content: space-between; making it dynamic. Is there a way to set the gap that way?

Comment: @КристиянИлиев, with the `gap` rule, you don't need to calculate the gaps between `item`. The spacing will be accurate even if you add `item` dynamically. This is the beauty of the `gap` rule.